# Python Needle in Haystack issue with return value / convert string to boolean

Tags: python, string, boolean

I´ve been trying to implement a simple needle in haystack function in Python to check if the word (needle) is part of the other string (haystack) and if yes output the index of the position. If the answer is no it should return "false" in boolean. My code looks as following:

```
def needleinhaystack(haystack,needle):

    for i in range(len(haystack) - len(needle)+1):
        if haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle:
            return i
    return "False"
```

It works but it return the false as a string

```
Expected return value: False (<class 'bool'>) 

Got return value: False (<class 'str'>)
```

I tried to fix it with a simple bool("False")

```
def needleinhaystack(haystack,needle):

    for i in range(len(haystack) - len(needle)+1):
        if haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle:
            return i
    return bool("False")
```

If I do that the whole script stops working.

Im pretty new to Python and a bit stuck any help is highly appreciated :-)

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just `return False`? Also, the boolean value of any non-empty string is true, including `bool("False")`. Python doesn't care about the meaning of your string.

Comment: Use: `return False`